# How to make click event work for multiple elements with the same class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to implement a flip effect on multiple tiles every time a user clicks on it, its sort of the beginning of a dashboard type webpage. How do I make a click event work for multiple classes of the same name?

All of the tiles have the same class name but under different "box" divs, the jquery click event only seems to implement in the last tile added, while the other ones are kept static. I can't seem to figure whats causing this and I've been searching all over for an answer. This is the last revision of the click event code:

```
var i = 0,
abbrs = document.getElementsByClassName("tile"),
len = abbrs.length;

function addEvent(abbr) {
    abbr.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        $(this).toggleClass("flip");
    })

}

for (i; i < len; i++){

    addEvent(abbrs[i]);
}
```

I can't seem to figure out where the root of the problem is.

Comment: Seems like your code does what you need? https://jsfiddle.net/L952e38a/

Comment: that's strange, perhaps all of the classes being inside different "box" divs is whats causing the problem?

Comment: might be. you can edit the post for more help. all the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/hendrikwegner/pen/gyNqwJ?editors=1111) for a pure javascript solution.

```
<p class="target">flip me</p>
<p class="target">flip me</p>
<p class="target">flip me</p>

.flipped {
  color: red;
}

const targets = document.getElementsByClassName('target');
for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
    targets[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.classList.toggle("flipped");
    })
}
```

Or consider [this for a jQuery solution](https://codepen.io/hendrikwegner/pen/vMqbVq).

```
<p class="target">flip me</p>
<p class="target">flip me</p>
<p class="target">flip me</p>

.flipped {
  color: red;
}

$('.target').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

**EDIT:**

After looking at your given code I just realized that you position absolute divs  via very large paddings which is not the correct way to do. Rather use `top|right|bottom|left` for positioning ([see here for docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/position)). After changing the css your example works fully even with the messy javascript. [Look here](https://codepen.io/hendrikwegner/pen/axeqdw)

Comment: Wow thanks so much for the help, it's definitely a lesson learned for me later down the road

Answer (score 1):

Note: here is the basic snippet that you need to do. by clicking all class listed call function to call show the effects. if you don't want to show effects then don't add class.

```js
function callMe(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('flip')){
        $(this).removeClass('flip');//removes flip class
    } else {
         $(this).addClass('flip');//add flip class
    }
}

$(".class1, .class2").click(callMe); //add classes here needs to give effects and call functions
```

```css
.flip{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">Class 1</div>
<span class="class2">Class 2</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that replacing the snippet you provided with this code should do it for you:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".tile").click(function() {         
            $(".tile").toggleClass("flip");
        });
    });
```

Depending on where the code actually lives in your project, you might not need the `$(document).ready()` event listener that wraps the "on click" event listener.

Comment: this seems to be closer to what I want, but its still only clickable during the last tile, and it flips all of them at once when i just want it one by one, thank you for the possible solution though.

Comment: I'm not sure where you placed the code I suggested. You should make sure that it is outside of any function as the code must be able to be executed when the page loads. If you can give IDs to your tiles, it would probably make it easier for you to only flip one card at a time. Or maybe use the "boxX" classes?